# Windows command prompt log errors to a file

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I have the following in command prompt, however not able to spool error logs to text files, what could be the reason?

```
eclipse.exe >d:\logt.txt
```

Comment: [Redirecting error messages from Command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110930)

Comment: If you need to see whats happening in Eclipse startup try this "c:\eclipse> eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe" to see a console. Default is javaw.exe windows wrapper so you don't get a console.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, link provided does help to solve my issue. Appreciated. if you post an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

At least on Windows 7 the following works in the default terminal

```
mycommand > log.txt 2> errorlog.txt
```

The `> log.txt` will catch the output to a file called "log.txt", and `2> errorlog.txt` will catch the errors to a file called "errorlog.txt"